# pl/sql two dimensional array - Cant get to item 2

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

In the following code example,

```
Type single_table_purge_type is varray(2) of varchar2(255);
Type single_table_list is table of single_table_purge_type; 

purge_table single_table_list;

purge_table := new single_table_list(
            new single_table_purge_type('product','Where product_id=5'),
            new single_table_purge_type('customer','Where customer_id=10')
);

For x in 1..purge_table.Count
        Loop
            For y in 1..purge_table(x).Count
            Loop
                DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( 'x='||x||' y='||y||' cell='||purge_table(x)(y));
            End loop;
        End loop;

DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( 'm1 ' || purge_table(1)(1));
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( 'm2 ' || purge_table(1)(2));
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( 'm3 ' || purge_table(2)(1));
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( 'm4 ' || purge_table(2)(2));
```

How can i get to the items (1,2) or (2,2)? (i.e. the where clauses). 
All i see is a duplicate of the first item when i print the values out.

Output

```
m1 product
m2 product
m3 customer
m4 customer
```

Comment: Can you please show us the right sql you had done? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running your code as shown (adding `declare`, `begin`, and `end`), I get the following on Oracle 10g:

```
x=1 y=1 cell=product
x=1 y=2 cell=Where product_id=5
x=2 y=1 cell=customer
x=2 y=2 cell=Where customer_id=10
m1 product
m2 Where product_id=5
m3 customer
m4 Where customer_id=10
```

This leads me to believe that there is something wrong in the way you are assembling the pieces you've shown us. Please edit your question to provide the script exactly as you run it.

(This really should have been a comment, but it requires length and formatting that wouldn't fit there.)

Comment: I was actually using a function during creation of the collection and it was returning the wrong value. Thanks